# Android WEB application without internet

Tags: php, android, html, android-studio, cross-platform

i am currently working on the idea of an application that can be used without internet connection(basically i open up the website i save  the website somewhere maybe in a cache and then i can use it offline and when i decide to open up the APP again with internet connection ill be updated to the latest version of the website,incase someone chSanged the database or added stuff etc...) now i wanted to know for starters if it's possible to make a mobile application using HTML/CSS/PHP/JS etc.. and in case it's possible is there a way to also have it work offline/online the way i mentioned?

for now i didn't try anything im still on the concept of the idea but for me what's ideal is to have it coded with HTML etc... and to be used offline when i don't have connection

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is a server-side technology, and so is the typical RDBMS (database) that the PHP talks to, you can have an app that connects to the PHP webserver and retrieves the data when online, and stores it locally in a smaller database like SQLite for offline usage. Usually android apps built like this will be constructed in a javascript [framework](https://reactnative.dev) made for the job, or [Flutter](https://flutter.dev).

Comment: i see,well at the same time i should have mentioned that i will be receiving data from the database of another phone application  which means it's not from a database that i create,so is there still a way to receive that database and store it for offline use ?

Comment: If the database you are interacting with is already on the phone, then it should already be capable of offline usage, as the phone cannot be expected to remain connected forever. In which case it will be available to your app, so long as the permissions and locations are good between the two apps. You would have to have the implicit assent of the other app developer to do that; otherwise next upgrade of their app will break yours.